# Finding all valid combinations of numeric inputs and operators in a Reverse Polish Notation expression

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

An arithmetic expression written in Reverse Polish (postfix) Notation is an ordered list of numbers and algebraic operators, which are sequentially evaluated as a stack would process them to return a single numeric result. If the expression contains n numbers, it must contain precisely (n-1) algebraic operators if every number and every operator is to be used in the evaluation of the result.  Also, the first two elements in the expression must be numbers, and the final element must be an operator - so the only elements in the sequence that can be *either* numbers *or* operators are the ones between these extremes, i.e. the 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc up to the last element but one (i.e. element no. (2n - 2), since there are (2n - 1) elements in the sequence.

I want to evaluate every possible combination of those intermediate elements, of which there are (n-2) numbers and (n-2) operators.  I know how many of them there *are*: it will be 2(n-2) choose (n-2), and generating all those permutations is a perfectly straightforward task - but in general, not all of them will deliver resolvable expressions.  For example if n = 4, there will be a total of 4C2 = 6 permutations that have two numbers in front and an operator at the end: if N represents a number and O an operator, they are NNNNOOO, NNNONOO, NNNOONO, NNONNOO, NNONONO and NNOONNO. However, the last of these six doesn't translate into a valid arithmetic expression, because after the second operation is performed the stack has been cleared (or to put it another way, within the first four elements of the sequence, the number of numbers doesn't exceed the number of operators). This particular example wouldn't actually fail to deliver a result if processed as a stack would handle it, but a sequence like NNOOONNNO where n = 5 wouldn't evaluate at all.

I could easily generate every possible permutation of the intermediate elements, and then run a check on them all to see which ones produce resolvable sequences, but I'd prefer if possible to generate *only* the resolvable sequences. Can anybody point me to an algorithm that will do this?

I've no doubt there *is* one, and that it's probably well known - but I haven't found a simple enough way to formulate the question to enable me to track it down via a search engine.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This really isn't my area so take this with a grain of salt. I have a hunch that working with an expression tree data structure directly is more likely to lend itself to a nice implementation than working with RPN. Your goal is to count the number of algebraic expressions, RPN is just one of many possible ways to write them down. You can always generate trees and convert them to RPN after the fact.

Comment: We're only talking about binary operators, right? NOOOOOO would be a perfectly valid sequency, if O is the unary -, for example.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it might be easier to only generate valid expressions if you start with an infix expression "tree" of your expression and convert that to RPN format if you really want to.

Each node can either be a binary operator $O$ or a number $N$. $O$ nodes by definition cannot be leaf nodes since they need exactly two child nodes, and $N$ nodes must be leaf nodes since they cannot have any children.

Because we know that $O$ nodes are never leaves and and $N$ nodes are always leaves, we don't even need to properly label them. At this point, we have transformed the problem into one where we need to generate all possible full binary trees with $N$ leaves (or alternatively, we want all possible full binary trees with $O+N=2N-1$ nodes total).
By full binary tree I mean that it is impossible for any $O$ node to have only 1 child; every node either has exactly 2 child nodes, or none.

There is a [recursive algorithm](https://anj910.medium.com/leetcode-894-all-possible-full-binary-trees-afa435ae698) which can be used to generate these trees for you. Here is a Python implementation example.

```
def gen_full_bst(N):
    # N >= 1 is the number of leaf (number) nodes
    # the string 'N' denotes a leaf node, and a tuple denotes an operator node.
    if N == 1:
        yield 'N'
    
    # allow N-n leaf nodes to belong to the left child, and the remainder belongs to the right child
    for n in range(1, N):
        left_N = N - n
        right_N = N - left_N
        for left_child in gen_full_bst(left_N):
            for right_child in gen_full_bst(right_N):
                yield (left_child, right_child)
```

To convert an infix tree tree to RPN format, just use a [post-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order,_LRN) of the BST. When a node is "visited" (not just traversed through), add that node to the bottom of your RPN stack.

```
def bst_to_rpn(tree):
    if tree == 'N':
        return 'N'
    return f'{bst_to_rpn(tree[0])}{bst_to_rpn(tree[1])}O'
```

Testing this for $N=4$:

```
for tree in gen_full_bst(4):
    print(bst_to_rpn(tree))
```

produces

```
NNONONO
NNNOONO
NNONNOO
NNNONOO
NNNNOOO
```

As a side-note, the way I implemented `gen_full_bst` doesn't have any intermediate caching of results; for example, `gen_full_bst(4)` calls `gen_full_bst(2)` 6 times in total. You can implement a look-up table where pre-computed values are stored and then reused to speedup the calculation at the cost of memory space. From some basic testing on my computer the non-caching version seems to be fine up to about $N=14$.